# How to access history of review audits

Tags: support, review-audits

I have just been banned from reviews for 1 month and have no idea why - I didn't fail a review immediately before the ban appeared (I've had a few fails before [mostly unfair, in my opinion]) so not sure if its a bug in the process or an error on my part.

Is there anywhere I can check my history to find out what happened? Or is there an appeal process?

Comment: Bans that last that long are probably mod-initiated. My guess is that the mod noticed that you had a long history of failing audits and decided to give you a break for a month.

Comment: Hard to be sure with my memory, but i estimate i've had no more than 5 failures in the six months i've been using the site. Would be nice to be able to check on my history to be sure though.

Comment: Your stats show you've approved 552 suggestions and rejected only 13 suggestions. Those numbers are not what they should be. Frankly, 5 failed audits is also *a lot*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I might have been the one to initiate a manual review ban on your account. I was looking into a series of users who had approved spam and vandalizing edits, and did a query on people with unnaturally high approval rates (as these users did). I saw that over the last 30 days you had approved 229 suggested edits and declined only 7 (in the last 14 days, you approved 118 edits and only rejected 1, a 99% approval rate). That is a ratio far out of whack with the normal quality level of suggested edits, so it looked like something strange was going on here.

The really weird thing was that you had only been presented with 1 audit over that entire time. We've had a couple of users find ways to game the audit system, and I suspected that might be the case. If I put the ban in place, it was probably to put a hold on your reviews until we figured out what was going on. Unfortunately, I can't check the history on this.

I've since heard from SE employees that there is nothing shady here, and that the lack of audits was a statistical anomaly, so I've unbanned your account from review. I went through all of your recent reviews and found no problems with any of them, so the approval rate also appears to be a fluke. You're totally innocent.

I'm sorry about the inconvenience. Robo-reviewers can do a lot of damage by letting in spam, trolling, and other harmful content, so I hope you can see why we wanted to put a halt on reviews and make sure everything was legit here. It appears that sometimes coin flips do all come up heads.

Comment: Thanks for unlocking me Brad :)

Comment: I might add that i have again been banned (for 7 days this time). Jeez

Comment: @LeeBurrows: Yes, due to http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2531291, http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/2530911, a little bit of http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2530838, other things in your most recent 30 or so reviews to varying effect, and the fact that all of the reviews in one hour and all of the reviews in another hour were either to approve or make no change. And a lot of them could have used a change. The fact that you’d been banned before (not counting this) didn’t help either.

Comment: hmm, i guess i'm out of touch on how strict to be

Answer (score 10):

I should elaborate on this a bit, since I was the one who actually suspended your access to review.

I reviewed your activity based on some concerns raised by a moderator (probably Brad [as he indicates in his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185359/how-to-access-history-of-review-audits/185373#185373)), but my full evaluation never got recorded or passed back to him (I was tied up elsewhere at the time and notified second-hand).

The original concern was that you weren't rejecting very many suggested edits, including some rather [useless](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2271561) formatting [changes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2271554). By and large, the edits you approved seemed reasonable, but it also came out that you'd failed 2 out of 3 review audits *and* skipped a whopping 72 additional audits. That's worrying: audits for suggested edits are fairly blatantly *bad* - if you're unable to hit that reject button when you come across them, then there's a pretty good chance you're either too hesitant to reject abusive behavior (folks do try to post spam via suggested edits) ...or you're just not paying any attention at all.

As I said, I don't think you've done any real harm with the edits you've approved so far, but please let this be a wake-up call: if you're not diligent in rejecting very poor edits, you're not being a diligent reviewer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shog9 - you're right that i haven't been rejecting many reviews recently - after a couple of failed audits that i considered completely unfair, i've tended to skip a review rather than reject it.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, your reviewing history is on your user page, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1901867/lee-burrows?tab=activity&sort=reviews).

From what I can tell, you were most likely suspected of robo-reviewing, as there are very few actions other than 'approve' in that list.

Comment: Does this list include the audits? I can't see any on the first couple of pages...

Comment: @user000001 I'm not sure. I don't use the review queues much, so audits may only be visible to the user who owns that page.

Comment: that list doesnt show the audits - only the 'real' reviews. In fact, it only shows reviews that i ok'ed - one's that i have flagged for attention are not even listed.

Comment: I checked my own review history and I can't find any audits, passed or failed, that way. I do a lot of reviewing so I may have missed them, but I don't think so.

Comment: Only review audits that you *pass* get listed in your activity history. Failed audits are never listed there. If you're still under 10,000 reputation, they do get listed in the history tab for that specific queue (if over 10k you'd probably never find them). I should also note that review audits are only identified as such when viewing the actual review item screen. They are not labeled as "Review Audit Passed/Failed" in the lists.

Comment: @animuson: the new *my review history* link now lets 10k+ users filter the history on their own reviews.